# SQL query for Select

Tags: sql

I have a table `Table1` with data like this:

```
User    Department       Location      Jan        Feb              
-----------------------------------------------------
P1        Admin          IND           1          0
P2        Admin          IND           1          1
P3        Admin          US            0          1
P1        HR             UK            1          0
P2        HR             UK            0          1
P1       Admin           AUS           1          1
P1       Admin           AUS           1          0
```

I need to get data from this table like:

```
Department            Jan                     Feb
-------------------------------------------------
Admin                 2                       3
HR                    1                       1
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: When you post a question, please take some time to format it properly. Refer to the Markdown formatting help if you need help with that. Questions that are easy to read are likely to get a better response, so you are likely to profit too from formatting properly. Thank you!

Comment: You need to **EXPLAIN** what it is you're trying to do - don't just dump two piles of data and let us *guess* what you want..... please **explain** in clears words what you're trying to get from the original set of data....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "2 3" is a typo and you actually meant admin is "4 3", the query is:

```
SELECT Department,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Jan = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Jan,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Feb = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Feb
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Department;
```

Comment: I'm *assuming* 2,3 was a mistake. Despite the question's lack of clarity, this looks like an answer to me. @ahmet To avoid deletion, you may want to rephrase your answer to explain how 4,3 makes more sense than 2,3 but to remove the request for clarification. Just a suggestion.